# Discord py. How to get if user is online without commands

Tags: discord, discord.py

i need a help with a python code. All I need is to get if user selected (by myself) ID is currently online. How can I do that?

The code for now looks like this, but its dosnt print anserw

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Member

TOKEN = "token"
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    return

@client.event
async def on_message(message, member : discord.Member=None):
    if member == MyID:
        print("draziv online")
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if "hello" in message.content or "hi" in message.content:
        return
        # await message.channel.send(f'Hello there {message.author.mention}. I hope you have a fantastic day so far. ')


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I was trying all the methods I found over the internet, but almost all of them are outdated

Comment: Presumably `member` is not just an id, but a full object.

Comment: @JohnGordon so, whats should I do to make it check to print "draziv online" atm? Do you have any idea?

Comment: The definitions I have seen online for the `on_message()` function have only the `message` argument.  How are you expecting the `member` argument to work?

Comment: I don't really know. All I need to get, if somebody says "hello", bot would greet them and after that send a specific message which include online admin mention. Something like "Hi (at)user. Currently (at)me is avaliable to help you" or smth like that

Comment: So you're saying you just added the `member` argument to the function definition on your own, and you're hoping it somehow works?

Comment: Not like that. I've try using it from someone who asked similar question to mine, but for me I didnt wanted to use commands. I thought all I need is do the same, but I've only added it onto on_message() and yeah, I was hoping it would work somehow